# Chat app with built-in music compositior and music send/share

Tags: android, music, music-production, music-composing, music-sheet

I am looking for a chat application with an integrated music composer, where you could also send music on staves.

The recipient sees a stave, with notes, and can click play below (amidst the chat).

Attachments, for various type of music, is accessed via plugins.

For accessibility, the phone's vibrator, would be used?

The app would be great, for blind people.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing Android app that does this – or do you want to collect ideas on how to write it? Your phrasing is a bit unclear.

Comment: I've been thinking this too! Why isn't there an extra tab on the google keyboard to put music on a stave and play it. When you've got a song stuck in your head that you don't know the name of, or if you want to "sing" to someone, or if you're artsy and want to share the melody you just came up with... There's plenty of use for it. It doesn't have to be complex (in my opinion). Sort of like the animal crossing tune maker (nooknet.net/tunes) except nicer, with room for more notes, and plugged into the existing keyboard :) (This is probably more complex to build than I think again :p things alway

Comment: I am not sure to understand this sentence: "Fire accessibility, the phone's vibrstoe, would be used?" Typos maybe?

Comment: I've updated my post.